# Redirect http to https with htaccess

Tags: html, redirect, https, no-www

Its a simple HTML website with apache server. How can I redirect HTTP to `https://www` with htaccess?

Need to redirect `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Rather than ask a super common question, you should start by looking for answers on this website, or via your favorite search engine, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following in the past with pretty good success -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.yourdomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found best code to do it. It's now working fine and safe.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```